# Convert string DateTime variable into real Datetime variable (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, strptime

I am a Stata user who is transitioning to Python. This should be a simple task but I am having trouble doing it. I need to generate a string datetime variable (object in Python) to a real datetime variable.

```
data = pd.read_csv("H://01_EXCEL_Reports).csv", sep='\t')
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
print(df["OCCURED_DT"])
print(df["OCCURED_DT"].dtypes)
OCCURED_DT2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(df["OCCURED_DT"], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Below are some example of my date variable.

```
2010-06-26 14:50:00
2010-08-09 17:15:00
2018-08-27 08:00:00

Name: OCCURED_DT, Length: 244835, dtype: object
```

This is the error I am getting.

```
OCCURED_DT2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(df["OCCURED_DT"], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series"
```

I tried to convert the OCCURED_DT to a real string just in case.

```
dtstr= str(df["OCCURED_DT"])
OCCURED_DT2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(dtstr, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

But I am still getting an error message.

```
line 9, in <module>
    OCCURED_DT2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(dtstr, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
line 577, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
line 359, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '0         2018-08-27 08:00:00\n1   …
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: You're mixing two libraries. You're using `pandas` and trying to use the `datetime` module in the standard library. You should use the [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) method of pandas. `pandas` is significantly different than core python; it's a substantial library aimed at scientific work

Comment: Thank you! I modified the code to: OCCURED_DT2 = pd.to_datetime(df["OCCURED_DT"], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") and it worked. I didn't know that when you import the pandas library you can not use  core python  codes. Again thank you!